# How get combobox text value with database in c#

Tags: c#, database, datagridview, combobox

I want to select an item from a combobox and it should show the item that has been selected.

When I use:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCateg", categCB.SelectedIndex);
```

it will only show the number of the item

if I use

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCateg", categCB.SelectedItem);
```

or

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCateg", categCB.SelectedItem.ToString());
```

It will only print a message like "System.Data.DataRowView"

Here's the whole Code:

```
private void GetCategory()
{
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from CategoryTBL", Con);
    SqlDataReader Rdr;
    Rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(String));
    dt.Load(Rdr);
    categCB.ValueMember = "CategoryName";
    categCB.DataSource = dt;

    Con.Close();
}

private void addbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (itemIDtxt.Text == "" || itemnametxt.Text == "" || descriptiontxt.Text == "" || manufacturertxt.Text == "" || amounttxt.Text == "" || quantitytxt.Text == "")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Missing Data");
    }
    else
    {
        int tAmount = Convert.ToInt32(amounttxt.Text) * Convert.ToInt32(quantitytxt.Text);

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ItemDetailTBL values(@iID, @ItemNa, @ItemCateg, @ItemDesc, @ItemMan, @ItemAmoun, @ItemQua, @ItemExDate, @ItemtAmount)", Con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Int32.Parse(itemIDtxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iID", itemIDtxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemNa", itemnametxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemCateg", categCB.SelectedIndex);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemDesc", descriptiontxt.Text.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemMan", manufacturertxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemAmoun", amounttxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemQua", quantitytxt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemExDate", expdatepick.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemtAmount", tAmount);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            MessageBox.Show("New Data Has been Added to the Inventory");
            Con.Close();
            Showitem();
            addHis();
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iID", itemIDtxt.Text);` Booo. Bad Programmer. Don't do that. Try not to use `AddWithvalue` as this allows the code to make assumptions on what exactly the variable type you are adding is.

Comment: Oh sorry I'm new, but thank you for the tip. I try not to do that again.

Comment: So what's the error because it seems a bit vague. Is it when you are INSERTing a value in `addbtn_Click`? If so what line?

Comment: When I select an Item from the combobox, it only show the index of the selected item on the database. I want it to show the selected Item's Name.

Comment: It is odd that the code is adding a column to the data table, THEN fills the data table. In other words… in the `GetCategory()` method you have the line of code… `dt.Columns.Add("CategoryName", typeof(String));` … ? … Why are you adding this column? If the `CategoryName` field/column does NOT exist in the returned table from the query, then it will be a blank/empty column. On the other hand… If the field/column DOES exist in the returned table, then, the line of code is superfluous. In either case, this needs clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pattern to following. Create a class representing the category table and override ToString with what should be shown in the ComboBox.

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => CategoryName;
}
```

Rewrite you code to read data to this pattern

```
public static List<Category> Categories()
{
    List<Category> list = new List<Category>() ;

    using var cn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    using var cmd = new SqlCommand { Connection = cn, 
        CommandText = "SELECT CategoryID ,CategoryName FROM dbo.Categories" };

    cn.Open();
    var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        list.Add(new Category() { CategoryID = reader.GetInt32(0), CategoryName = reader.GetString(1) });
    }

    return list;
}
```

The `method above` for this example resides in a `class named SqlServerOperations`.

Form code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        categCB.DataSource = SqlServerOperations.Categories();
    }

    private void GetCurrentCategoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var current = (Category)categCB.SelectedItem;
        MessageBox.Show($"{current.CategoryID,-5}{current.CategoryName}");
    }
}
```

[image]